# bow toolkit ubuntu /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [rainbow] Error 1

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

while Installing Bow toolkit in ubuntu 12.04, the following error occurs
$make

gcc-3.4 -lnsl  -L. -lbow -L./argp -largp -lm -lcrypt -g -O -Wall -Wimplicit -o rainbow rainbow.o active.o deflexer.o em.o emsimple.o kl.o knn.o maxent.o naivebayes.o nbshrinkage.o nbsimple.o prind.o tfidf.o svm_base.o svm_smo.o svm_al.o svm_trans.o svm_fisher.o

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rainbow] Error 1
Help to resove

Comment: Some newer versions of Gcc are picky about argument order, try moving the `-o rainbow` last?

Comment: In fact, all the `-l<whatever>` should be last, as well. `gcc` has a tendency to process things left-to-right (weird, huh?), which can cause unexpected/hard-to-explain issues, especially during the link phase, when things are "out of order"...

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar linker error (/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s) trying to run ./configure for an emacs 24.3 source bundle with gcc 4.7.2.  I was able to find exactly what ld was looking for by wrapping the gcc call with "strace -f":

```
strace -f gcc conftest.c > strace.dump 2>&1
```

It turned out gcc and ld were looking for libgcc_s.so and libgcc_s.so.1.  I did have libgcc installed (in my case, 'yum install libgcc47.i686'), but these two files were not, as such, in the paths ld and gcc were checking.  The solution was simply:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/libgcc_s-4.7.2-20120921.so.1 /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
sudo ln -s /lib64/libgcc_s-4.7.2-20120921.so.1 /lib64/libgcc_s.so
```